# loop <a> search complete page <a>add as friend</a> and click all links on load (NO ID)

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<a href="do.php?ac=add_friend&amp;id=142077&amp;align=0" target="doframe" class="black_link">add as friend</a>
```

No need of referring href.  just search "add as friend" trap in the loop particular anchor and fire click event on load.  once i open the page all the anchor tags having "add as friend" should be clicked.  no page redirection or opening.  just click. here is the code please help out.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("a:contains('add as friend')").each(function () {

        $store = $(this).text();
        if ($store == 'add as friend') {
            //do Anything.....
            //Here i need to loop get the anchor tag and click automatic
//please not there is no id.

        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Clicking a number of links in direct succession is likely not going to achieve what you want - most likely the browser will simply cancel the request caused by “clicking” the first link as soon as you click the second one - after all, this indicates the user’s wish to navigate elsewhere, and in such a situation browsers tend to cancel pending requests. That is, if those are “normal” links; if any kind of event handling is going on to suppress the default action, and makes the requests in the background instead, then [triggering](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) a click might work.

Comment: Hi manually when i click it, no page redirection.  for example follow and unfollow that is.  <a href="do.php?ac=add_friend&amp;id=142077&amp;align=0" target="doframe" class="black_link">add as friend</a>

Answer (score 0):

Just do it

```
var allLinks = $("a:contains('add as friend')");

allLinks.each(function(){
    $(this).on("click",function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
        console.log("called");
    });

    $(this).trigger("click");
})
```

Example  - https://jsfiddle.net/ucz0x3td/

Comment: Hello Manoj, Thanks for your help.  console.log is working but not click.  am using js 2.1.  am using a google extension to execute this query of external site with supports 2.1.0.  any more help can be provided ?

Comment: @ajay, try `$(this).click()` instead of trigger to see if it helps.

Comment: I have done R&D it getting the href to click.  we need the Anchor tag link to be clicked.  please help.

Comment: @ajay, It should work though. As far as an extension is concerned; I am not sure of that.